# Creating and selecting data from a view in asp.net not happening?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008, view

I am trying to write a view and retrieve data from that view, I have done this :

```
 string command = "if OBJECT_ID('try1') IS NOT NULL Drop view try1" +"\n"+"go"+"\n";
        command = command + "Create view try1 as select WBSCode,Description,TerritoryCode,AmountReleased,convert(varchar(25),CreatedOn,106) as CreatedOn,IsEnable from WBS where WBSCode like '%" + msrch + "%'";
        command = command +"\n"+"go"+"\n"+"select WBSCode,Description,TerritoryCode,AmountReleased,convert(varchar(25),CreatedOn,106) as CreatedOn,IsEnable from try1 where TerritoryCode in (select TerritoryCode from Territory where StateCode='" + mbcode + "')";
        SqlCommand cmdd = new SqlCommand(command);
        cmdd.Connection = con;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            mngwbsGV1.DataSource = dt;
            mngwbsGV1.DataBind();
        }
```

but the issue is i am getting an error in `da.Fill(dt)` that:

> *Incorrect syntax near 'go'.
>
>   'CREATE VIEW' must be the first statement in a query batch.
>
>   Incorrect syntax near 'go'.*

But when I am running this in my SQL Server 2008 it's running but not retrieving the data

What should I do?

Comment: You should **create** your view separately - not in the middle of retrieving data from it! Then, in your ASP.NET - only `SELECT` from that view. Also: `GO` is a SQL Server Mgmt Studio delimiter - it's **not** a SQL keyword....

Comment: but the thing is i need to delete this view also

Comment: USE ";" in place of "GO"..

Comment: But if you drop the view right away after use - what good is it at all?? What are you **really** trying to achieve here?? It seems to me using a view here looks like the wrong approach...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be creating your view separately, e.g. during installation or version upgrade - using regular SQL scripts.

If you **must** do this in code - you need to do it this way:

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(--your connection string here--))
{
    SqlCommand dropView = new SqlCommand("IF OBJECT_ID('try1') IS NOT NULL DROP VIEW try1", conn);

    conn.Open();

    dropView.ExecuteNonQuery();

    SqlCommand createView = new SqlCommand("CREATE VIEW try1 AS SELECT WBSCode, Description, TerritoryCode, AmountReleased, CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), CreatedOn, 106) AS CreatedOn, IsEnable FROM WBS ", conn);

    createView.ExecuteNonQuery();

    conn.Close();
}
```

and then you can select from it using this (use a **parametrized query** instead of concatenating together your SQL command to avoid SQL injection attacks and to improve performance!):

```
SqlCommand selectCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT WBSCode, Description, TerritoryCode, AmountReleased, CreatedOn, IsEnable FROM try1 WHERE TerritoryCode IN (SELECT TerritoryCode FROM Territory WHERE WBSCode LIKE @msrch AND StateCode = @mbcode", conn);

selectCmd.Parameters.Add("@msrch", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = "%" + msrch + "%";
selectCmd.Parameters.Add("@mbcode", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = mbcode;

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(selectCmd);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);

if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    mngwbsGV1.DataSource = dt;
    mngwbsGV1.DataBind();
}
```

But then again: if you have such a simple select - what do you need a view for in the first place, especially if you just want to create it, select from it, and drop it again right away. Doesn't make any sense at all ....